# Plotting categorical variable over multiple numeric variables in python

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, scatter-plot

I need to plot one categorical variable over multiple numeric variables.

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
                          party  media_user  business_user      POLI      mass
0                       Party_a    0.513999       0.404201  0.696948  0.573476
1                       Party_b    0.437972       0.306167  0.432377  0.433618
2                       Party_c    0.519350       0.367439  0.704318  0.576708
3                       Party_d    0.412027       0.253227  0.353561  0.392207
4                       Party_e    0.479891       0.380711  0.683606  0.551105
```

And I would like a scatter plot with different colors for the different variables; eg. one plot per party per [media_user, business_user, POLI, mass] each in different color.

So like this just with scatters instead of bars:

[image: bar chart]

The closest I've come is this

```
sns.catplot(x="party", y="media_user", jitter=False, data=sns_df, height = 4, aspect = 5);
```

producing:

[image: cat_scat_plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By messing around with some other graphs I found that by simply adding  `linestyle = ''` I could remove the line and add markers. Hope this may help somebody else!

```
sim_df.plot(figsize = (15,5), linestyle = '', marker = 'o')
```

[image]